# Use IR remote with arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, led, ir, remote-control

I would like to use the IR remote with Arduino to turn on a LED and turn off the same LED when I push on the remote.

That is to say :

- If I push on 1 I would like the LED turn on
- If I push on 2 I would like the LED turn off

Here is my code :

```
#include <IRremote.h>

const int RECV_PIN = 7;
IRrecv irrecv(RECV_PIN);
decode_results results;

const int L1 = 13;

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
  irrecv.enableIRIn();
  irrecv.blink13(true);
  pinMode(L1, OUTPUT);
}

void loop(){
  if (irrecv.decode(&results)){
        unsigned int value = results.value;
        Serial.println(value);
        irrecv.resume();
        if(value == 12495){
        digitalWrite(L1, HIGH);
        delay(1000);
        } 
        else if(value == 6375){
        digitalWrite(L1, LOW);
        delay(1000);  
      }

  }
}
```

But the problem is when I push on 1 I just see the LED turn on but very quickly the LED turns off then whereas I don't push on the button 2.

Could you help me please?

Comment: Unrelated; there is no need to add the `delay(1000);` after turning the led on/off.

Answer (score 1):

This line of your sketch `irrecv.blink13(true);` tells the `IRrecv` object to flash the LED on and off when an IR signal is received. `boarddefs.h` in the IRremote folder has pin number 13 defined as the default `BLINKLED`. The code you have written in `loop()` is trying to do something different with the same LED. I would remove this line `irrecv.blink13(true);` then try your sketch again. Once the LED is working correctly, try removing both of these lines `delay(1000);`.